# Common regex generation java library

Tags: software-development, library, java, regex

I'm looking for a Java library which can generate common regular expressions, such as:

- numbers of *n* digits
- alphanumeric sequences (no special chars)
- URLs
- email addresses
- IP addresses
- etc.

The generated pattern must be compatible with the `java.util.regex` API.

Comment: This sounds implausible.  What would this hypothetical library generate the regexes from?  An input language that is capable of expressing those things would be just as complicated as regexes.

Comment: @StephenC For example, compare `HypotheticalLib.email()` with `Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$")`.